# Convert svn externals with copy of corresponding branches

Tags: svn, branch, externals

I have a project with many externals, with often branching. When branching I use http://svnxf.codeplex.com to freeze externals to specific revision. But after this impossible to commit in frozen external. Is there a way to automatically replace this frozen externals with a real branches with externals revision?

Comment: So, you want to remove the external definition but keep the folder structure that the external brought down? Sure, but then if you need a different revision of the external, you'd have to remember to update your now-regular-folder with the new version of the external (through a manual operating system copy, not through SVN or externals).

Comment: I want to find a way to replace externals with copies of corresponding branches. When committing I need to merge differences in trunk, this is not a problem. But there is 30-40 externals, and changing it manually - hard work. I need to find automatically way.

Comment: I think I see what you mean: trunk has an external pointing to the trunk branch of project X, while your branches have externals pointing to a branch of project X. There is a way, using a post-commit hook.

Comment: stop using svn:externals, they're part of your problem, not your solution.  Why do you use them?

Comment: We have many projects with many common projects. Every day changes appears in common projects. So, Nuget for example - not a solution, because uncomfortably to edit dependencies separately, then rebuild project for testing, then commit dependencies, then update dependencies. Which alternative? Merging every commit into 20-30 places?